# If $a >1$, $b >1$ and $p = \frac{\log_b{(\log_b{a})}}{\log_b{a}}$, then what's $a^p$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> If $a >1$, $b >1$ and $p = \frac{\log_b{(\log_b{a})}}{\log_b{a}}$, then what's $a^p$?

My steps:

$$a^p=a^{\frac{\log_b{(\log_b{a})}}{\log_b{a}}}$$

But from then I had no idea what to do and would like assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have by [change of base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base)
$$
\frac{\log_b(\log_b(a))}{\log_b(a)} = \log_a(\log_b(a))
$$
Therefore,
$$
a^p = \log_b(a)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $p = \frac{\log_b{(\log_b{a})}}{\log_b{a}},$ so $p\log_b{a} = \log_b{(\log_b{a})},$ and finally $\log_b{a^p} = \log_b{(\log_b{a})}.$

Answer (score 1):

$ p = \frac{\log_b{(\log_b{a})}}{\log_b{a}} => p = \log_a{(\log_b(a))} => a^p = \log_b{a} $ . Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

Hint: since the "outer" logarithms are $\log_b {(\text{stuff})}$ you might think that you need $b^{\text{something}}$ rather than $a^{\text{something}}$ - fortunately, using logarithms, you can write $a=b^{?}$